# Request.user has no attribute user when used in settings.py

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

request.user generates a `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'` error when I try to use it in my settings.py file. Am I doing something wrong?

Settings.py:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    if DEBUG:
        return True
    #if not request.is_ajax() and request.user and request.user.UserSettings.debugger:
    #    return True
    return False
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'acacia2.settings.show_toolbar',
}
```

Comment: Man, where can I start. Please read the docs carefuly first. TLDR; Settings are established statically before any connection goes to the server so you cannot get request inside something that has to be static before server starts.  Settings are set per-server-startup not per-request. Treat is as a pre-server-startup config. Once more please read the docks before actual coding. It will make stack less messy. Cheers

Comment: @quqa123 whilst what you say about settings being set at server start-up is correct. However, the OP is defining a callback function. The setting simply points to the callback function, so that it can be used later, on a per-request basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure without seeing your list of middleware, but this is what I suspect is happening:

#### Why does it not work

- The `user` attribute is set by the `contrib.auth` middleware.
- The function that you define above gets called by the
  django-debug-toolbar middleware.

If your django-debug-toolbar middleware is before the `contrib.auth` middleware in the list of middleware defined in your `MIDDLEWARE` setting, then when the request reaches your debug-toolbar middleware it won't have had a user object set on it yet. Hence your error (`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`).

#### How to fix it

Make sure the django-debug-toolbar middleware goes after the auth middleware, e.g:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ...

]
```

Comment: I don't think any of this will work as he's trying to call view inside settings.py

Comment: No, he is not calling the function inside settings. He is defining the function inside settings. When the request passes through the debug-toolbar middleware, it looks up the value of `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK` - which is a string. The middleware imports the function from `settings.py` and it is inside the middleware that the function is then called (with the request object). This is perfectly legitimate.